# Setting Android 10 Dark theme on and off with adb shell - how to do it without reboot?

Tags: dark-mode

To Enable Dark Mode:

> `adb shell settings put secure ui_night_mode 2`

To Disable Dark Mode:

> `adb shell settings put secure ui_night_mode 1`

For Auto Dark Mode:

> `adb shell settings put secure ui_night_mode 0`

and then

> `adb reboot`

My question is how to change Dark mode without `abd reboot` ?

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me, no need for root.

`adb shell "cmd uimode night yes"`

Answer (score 3):

On root devices

To Enable Dark Mode:

```
adb shell "su 0 cmd uimode night yes"
```

To Disable Dark Mode:

```
adb shell "su 0 cmd uimode night no"
```

For Auto Dark Mode:

```
adb shell "su 0 cmd uimode night auto"
```